# Proteus I2C debugger sends additional byte with right shift, but ATmega32 gets left shifted one

Tags: c, avr, i2c, proteus

ATmega32 should work as a slave for collecting data and GPIO control. I2C parcel should look like
S (address) (register) ([value] )P
But if I send P condition after register specifying, Proteus automatically sends additional byte that right shifted even after NACK. MCU gets register left-shifted. I use Atmel Studio 7 with built-in SDK. How to fight this problem?

I2C interrupt service routine

```
ISR(TWI_vect)
{
    //cli();
    
  switch(TW_STATUS)
  {
    case TW_SR_DATA_ACK:
      // received data from master, call the receive callback
      // расчет на то, что при приеме данных первым байтом 
      // будет регистр, куда будут записываться данные
      I2C_recv(TWDR, is_data_recv);
      
      if (is_data_recv == 0) {
          is_data_recv = 1;
          I2C_ack();
      }
      else I2C_nack();
      //TWCR = (1<<TWIE) | (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEA) | (1<<TWEN);
      break;
    case TW_ST_SLA_ACK:
      // master is requesting data, call the request callback
      I2C_req();
      //TWCR = (1<<TWIE) | (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEA) | (1<<TWEN);
      break;
    case TW_ST_DATA_ACK:
      // master is requesting data, call the request callback
      I2C_req();
      //TWCR = (1<<TWIE) | (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEA) | (1<<TWEN);
      break;
    case TW_BUS_ERROR:
      // some sort of erroneous state, prepare TWI to be readdressed
      TWCR = 0;
      //TWCR = (1<<TWIE) | (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEA) | (1<<TWEN); 
      break;
    case TW_SR_STOP:
      is_data_recv = 0;
      I2C_on_stop();
      //TWCR = (1<<TWIE) | (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEA) | (1<<TWEN);
      break;
    default:
      //TWCR = (1<<TWIE) | (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEA) | (1<<TWEN);
      break;
  }
  
  
  //sei();
  //TWCR |= (1<<TWINT);
  TWCR |= (1<<TWIE) | (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN);
}
```

I2C callbacks

```
// Прием по I2C регистров/данных
// Getting register/data from I2C
void i2c_receive_cb(uint8_t byte_received, uint8_t is_data) {
    if (is_data == 0) regaddr = byte_received;
    else regdata = byte_received;
}

// Выдача данных при задание одного из регистров на чтение
// Putting data to I2C if register is read-register
void i2c_response_cb() {
    uint8_t data_out = 0;
    //uint8_t ack = 0;
    switch (regdata)
    {
    case GET_ANALOG:
        data_out = (data_block % 2 == 0 ? analog_h[data_block] : analog_l[data_block]);
        data_block++;
        if (data_block > 15) {
            data_block = 0;
            I2C_nack();
        }
        else {
            I2C_ack();
        }
        //ack = 0;
        break;
    case GET_ERRORS:
        data_out = 0x66;                // Выдача кода ошибки
        I2C_nack();
    }
    
    I2C_transmitByte(data_out);
}

// Применение данных из регистра на запись, или сброс счетчика блоков данных
// Applying data from write registers or reset data blocks counter
void i2c_on_stop_cb() {
    data_block = 0;
}
```

[Project link](https://yadi.sk/d/IJYcI0Ulh9lTJQ)

[Proteus screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxfxD.png)

Comment: try to make `regaddr` and `regdata` (and all other variables which are altered from interrupts) - `volatile`

Comment: It made no effect. But I noticed a Proteus I2C debugger bug: if you send an entire sequence, there is a bug foresaid. But if you send from I2C debugger in step-by-step mode, you should make at least two steps since the start till the stop before you send a byte.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,** you can use the i2c-unit driver, this driver has been tested and not has any problem,
this driver has been used in many library and codes!

[Driver Link](https://github.com/Majid-Derhambakhsh/i2c-unit)

Comment: Which projects this lib used in? I'd like you to add examples and/or docs. I interested in I2C slave mode